# Nebular: Layout-Header how to add a bootstrap dropdown to the component

Tags: nebular

My company is very new to Nebular and we have a standard header that includes a user dropdown (bootstrap) that i would like to include into nb-layout-header.

Is this possible and if so how can this be achieved. here are snippets of our code:

MainPage:

```
<nb-layout center>  
  **<nb-layout-header fixed>
      <nb-header></nb-header>
  </nb-layout-header>**

  <nb-sidebar class="menu-sidebar"
              tag="menu-sidebar"
              responsive>
    <nb-sidebar-header>
      </i> Menu </span>-->
      <nb-menu [items]="sidebarHeaderMenu" (click)="toggleSideBar()"> </nb-menu>

    </nb-sidebar-header>
    <nb-menu [items]="subMenu"></nb-menu>
  </nb-sidebar>


  <nb-layout-column>

    <!--<router-outlet></router-outlet>-->
    <span style="width: 100vw">Place holder</span>

  </nb-layout-column>


  <nb-layout-footer>
  </nb-layout-footer>
</nb-layout>*
```

nb-header code:

```
<div class="header-container">
     <div class="logo-container">        
        <div class="logo" (click)="goToHome()">
          <img class="header-logo" src="../../assets/images/mylogo.png" alt="My LOGO">
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The dropdown above does not event display in the layout header. Any help would be appreciated..

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Some Bootstrap components require the use of JavaScript to function ([Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/#js)), so make sure you include all required files in `angular.json`. It should look something like this:

```
  "styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
  ],
```

Also, you need to add [`@nebular/bootstrap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nebular/bootstrap) package to make nebular work with bootstrap. See the [docs](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/guides/bootstrap-integration#bootstrap-integration) for guidance.

And by the way, usually, Bootstrap and jQuery isn't used directly in Angular apps. There is [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/) package, for example. Then you don't need jQuery and Bootstrap js files.